# Fit a curve/model to 1/x data

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataset that follows the pattern of a 1/x curve. I would like to fit a curve to the data with a model.

I have tried using a polynomial function, but it doesn't quite look right because the polynomial curves back up, whereas my data asymptotes at the bottom. I know that I'm just missing some terminology here, but how can I do the curve? Is there a name for the 1/x curve?

```
x<-rep(1:20)
y<-1/x

fit <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))
plot(x, y)
points(x, predict(fit), type="l", col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image: example graph]

Comment: Can you try `lm(y ~ I(1/x))`?

Comment: Thank you! What does the `I` stand for/do?

Comment: The graph doesn't look like f(x)  = 1/x as it increases after x = 15. You may try higher order polynomials or nonlinear least squares estimation (nls(), nls2()).

Answer (score 4):

It's not working because you're forcing it to be a 2-degree polynomial with `poly(x, 2)`.

You'll want to create some other variable that is the transformation of your `x` value, and then run the regression on that:

```
x <- rep(1:20)
transformedx <- 1/x

y <- 1/x

fit <- lm(y ~ transformedx)
plot(x, y)
points(x, predict(fit), type="l", col="red", lwd=2)
```

For compactness you can simply write the formula in the `lm` line using the `I` function as Mike.Gahan pointed out:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ I(1/x))
```

Naturally this will be a perfect fit because you're mapping a function onto itself, but I'm assuming that in reality your `y` values are coming from data source that isn't a perfect match to `1/x`.

Comment: But, as the comments point out,  `lm` works just fine fitting directly to `1/x` . No need for the external conversions.

Comment: Yup exactly, but I want to emphasize that it needs to be regressed on a transformation, not the original sequence.