# How do i adjust a predicted log function so it is closer to my data points?

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following data (N=100):

```
data <- c(0.00625184781684353,0.00476045914992689,0.00410579590496692,0.00364190024330886,0.00330959588679313,0.00295162467178293,0.00294139180137722,0.00309671219181701,0.00275951517937275,0.00259638723910849,0.00255055235436329,0.00253639564250565,0.00245535559384006,0.00228326375027479,0.00223552980728776,0.00256747699305967,0.00236892396756154,0.00223789975401336,0.00227117347429151,0.00221586146913485,0.0022126769368319,0.00227402304510622,0.0021468617279666,0.00225341888941175,0.00211058992596496,0.00219476252758117,0.00210173301929526,0.00227560193923749,0.00203577505430919,0.00203318498773805,0.00201499827623374,0.00213377036862111,0.00206677581233842,0.00195908442478977,0.0019074281942733,0.00219326497963758,0.00209439107947152,0.00207351039547349,0.00212462221193429,0.00195082242453627,0.00201628705333334,0.0019459203467357,0.00201864564961588,0.00207500005646203,0.0019938335042378,0.00191824828638271,0.00185918053681837,0.00198330566751539,0.0020937511770958,0.00204318381191582,0.00188128649781538,0.00196154000701513,0.00200027621624583,0.0019031292568209,0.0019753645338664,0.00194343623099681,0.00196234854381748,0.00181813976154867,0.00185406846974441,0.0018843993826779,0.00196087591340332,0.00191469615832241,0.0018892813892349,0.00183363182300353,0.00194453589002172,0.00187398813393513,0.0020276166397646,0.00198038284208184,0.00196217220130672,0.00195852945385389,0.00177850240578155,0.00180944090794838,0.00187680265865063,0.00190294215181125,0.00186901596278278,0.00196375687750163,0.00187750813211545,0.00184528196260878,0.00186578257197937,0.00192412901406411,0.00185024869288581,0.0018639679556602,0.00182641530017768,0.00177603379012923,0.0018389901669527,0.0018349308865919,0.00181465024821425,0.00179648127204045,0.00187579404215745,0.00187312385928857,0.00180997375009525,0.00188721222926752,0.00188570075420681,0.00188739190357344,0.00182526851985943,0.00193092855207866,0.00179597246861001,0.00188372398815342,0.00179976677825106,0.00196100767251016)
```

I have plotted these points in ggplot and this is the result:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,y=data)
ggplot2::ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(x,y))
```

[image: raw data points]

I want to fit a curve through those points. I suspect the data to behave close to a log-function so i fitted one with the predict function and added it to the plot:

```
logpredict <- lm(df$y ~ log(df$x))
ggplot2::ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line(data=data.frame(df$x,predict(logpredict)),aes(x=df$x,y=predict.logpredict.),color="red3")
```

[image: log plot]

This is pretty close to the result i am looking for, but i am not satisfied with the fit. I am not sure how to describe it properly, but i want the curve to be... "curvier", meaning that it be closer to the actual data points. So lower for 10 < x < 50 and higher for 50 < x < 100.

I am guessing that my data isn't as close to the log-function as i thought, but how can i adapt my predict function to get a tighter fit?

Edit: For example, the Log-Function gets closer and close to 0, while i suspect my data to converge not towards 0, but towards a value ~0.0017.

Comment: You probably want `log(y) ~ x`, also this should be on stats.SE, also post actual data

Comment: I will try with log(y) ~ x, but i am unsure about your other two comments. What is stats.SE? And I have provided the actual data, it is right at the start.

Comment: When using  `predict(lm(log(df$y) ~ df$x))` i get values around -6, so unless i need to adjust other things aswell, this doesn`t seem to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closer consideration, the fact that i felt like that the log-function was not a good fit for my data lead me to looking for other possible functions that may close resemble my data.

With the help of this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880938/fit-a-curve-model-to-1-x-data) i used

```
fit <- lm(df$y ~ I(1/df$x))
ggplot2::ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line(data=data.frame(df$x,predict(fit)),aes(x=df$x,y=predict.fit.),color="red3")
```

to get this plot:
[image: newplot]

which i feel is a better fit for my data.