# Problem with lm() giving incorrect result when using 1/var as second variable

Tags: r, lm

I have a dataframe with two variables that I will plot with the inverse of the varaibles and make a linear regression on this.

```
linear_mod <- lm((1/df$var1[3:length(var1)]) ~       # 3 because the first two are 0 and would result in 1/0
                 (1/df$var2[3:length(var2)]))
png("lineweaver-burk_glc6p.png", height = 400)
plot(1/(df$var1), 1/(df$var2))
abline(linear_mod)
```

however this just results in y=0.897, with no slope.

I know I can assign 1/var to two variables and use them to get it to work like so

```
temp1 <- 1/df$var1[3:length(df$var1)]
temp2 <- 1/df$var2[3:length(df$var2)]
```

which does result in a correct regression line (0.83022 + 0.01768x), but I would like to know what causes the lm() function to not function when using the above.

I have tested using one temp variable and one explicitly written out, and this only gives a slope when the temp variable occupies the second spot, so the lm() function only seem to accept the 1/df$var1[3:length(var1)] if it is before ~, and not after ~.

Changing it to just be without 1/ on the second variable makes it give a slope.

```
linear_mod <- lm((1/df$var1[3:length(var1)]) ~       # 3 because the first two are 0 and would result in 1/0
                 (df$var2[3:length(var2)]))
```

and putting for example 2+df$var... as the second variable also gives a slope, thus there seem to be something specific with `/` and it seems to be an inconsistency between using this math in the first and second variable and I wonder why this is the case. Putting the second variable inside c() does make it work, but I don't see why that wouldn't also be necessary for the first variable.

Here is a teble with the variables in the dataframe.
|var2|var1              |
|----|------------------|
|0  |0.0133976420150054 |
|0  |0.00803858520900322|
|0.1|1.17363344051447   |
|0.1|1.13076098606645   |
|0.2|2.05787781350482   |
|0.2|2.18113612004287   |
|0.2|1.7524115755627    |
|0.2|0.844051446945338  |
|0.2|1.42550911039657   |
|0.3|0.244908896034298  |
|0.3|0.616291532690247  |
|0.3|1.39067524115756   |
|0.3|0.669882100750268  |
|0.3|1.66934619506967   |
|0.3|1.56752411575563   |
|0.3|1.33976420150054   |
|0.4|1.83547695605573   |
|0.4|1.77920685959271   |
|0.5|1.83547695605573   |
|0.5|1.84887459807074   |
|1  |1.92390139335477   |
|2  |1.94533762057878   |
|2  |1.7470525187567    |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can try something like `lm(y ~ I(1/x))` if you don't want to specify an external variable (means to treat the expression "as is" rather than as part of a formula). Look at the documentation for `?formula` or see the responses here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880938/fit-a-curve-model-to-1-x-data

Comment: Using 1/x inside a formula is equivalent to doing `1 + x %in% 1`. i.e. fit the model `y~1`, with just an intercept.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it, but am I understanding correctly that only the second variable is treated as part of a formula and that is why it is only necessary on the second variable?

Answer (score 0):

When using the formula interface with lm(), you need to use the **I()** notation in your formula. Check **?formula** for more details. This is because the division operator **/** is not working element-wise but performs a single division on the whole vector which therefore you get a single scalar value. Therefore, If you want to perform regression using inverse of variables you must use the **I()** function to tell R to treat the division as an element-wise operation. Also to skip the first two rows of your data you can simply add **data=df[-c(1:2),]** inside **lm()** function. , like this:

```
linear_mod <- lm(I(1/var1) ~ I(1/var2), data=df[-c(1:2),])
```

Hope it could helps